# Custom field is not being displayed on mobile

Tags: acumatica

I have been trying to display custom field 'WorkflowState' on mobile, but it is not working.
Here is the custom field:
[image]

And here is the field name from service description of appointments page.
[image]

And this is how I have edited Appointments page for mobile:
[image]

But, the field is not being displayed in mobile
[image]

I even tried using another custom field 'ProjectEstimatedRemainingHours', but that didn't work too.

But if I add other field from Appointments page which are not custom, then it works fine.

I have had displayed custom fields in mobile in 6.1. And, now as I have upgraded the instance to 17.205, then it stopped working. Is there anything that I missing or some changes in the new version?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, I was editing wrong file. After Service Management is implemented as a Feature in 2017 R2 version, Appointments List page in mobile is related to Appointment History (FS400100) page. So, I had to had add these custom fields in grid and that fixed the problem.